# Generating spatially correlated statistical noise using autocorrelation and python

Tags: python, noise, pydicom, autocorrelation, medical-imaging

I’m trying to emulate the methodology described in this paper:
http://www.ajnr.org/content/34/8/1506
under the heading “Noise Addition to Simulate Dose Reduction”
As far as I understand the authors basically completed the following steps.

1. First, measure the spectral properties of CT noise from the phantom data
2. Compute the noise autocorrelation function was computed from these data
3. Generate window around the autocorrelation peak and save as a convolution filter
4. To generate noise with a proper power spectrum apply this filter to white Gaussian noise and scaled to the desired standard deviation.

The generated spatially correlated noise can subsequently be added to real CT images of patients to generate CT images with noise having the same spectral properties as the phantom scan.

Link to dicom file of phantom scan: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ouFfqSxWo7PFV4CXhYI1TEbNZp-vM8Bq/view?usp=sharing

Goole colab with outputshttps://colab.research.google.com/drive/1utFiDNbElyeKGuyeHg3_rVG4ZDc5xoHQ?usp=sharing

And python code found below.

The spatially correlated statistical noise I’m able to generate seems to be be too blurred and not correspond to the spectral properties found in the Phantom scan.

I was wondering if anyone can see where I go wrong?

Kind regards
/////////

```
#! pip install pydicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pydicom
import pydicom.data
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft
from numpy import zeros
from scipy import signal

base = ""
pass_dicom1 = "Catphan36A.dcm"  # Phantom noise data

filename = pydicom.data.data_manager.get_files(base, pass_dicom1)[0]
ds = pydicom.dcmread(filename)

print("# show CT of phantom")
plt.imshow(ds.pixel_array, cmap=plt.cm.bone)  
plt.show()

n=512 # get center 128x128 pixels of phantom  scan, i.e. the uniform noise
dataNoise= ds.pixel_array
dataNoise = dataNoise[int(n*(3/8)):int(n*(3/8))+int(n/4), int(n*(3/8)):int(n*(3/8))+int(n/4)]

print("Show 12x128 uniform noise from Phantom")
plt.imshow(dataNoise, cmap="gray")  # show 12x128 uniform noise from Phantom
plt.show()

# do 2d DT of the phantom noise 
dataNoiseFT = np.fft.ifft2(dataNoise)

# compute the autocorrelation function of the phantom noise and shift the data to center to obtain kernel
dataAC = np.fft.ifft2(dataNoiseFT*np.conjugate(dataNoiseFT))
shiftedAC = np.fft.fftshift(dataAC)

print("Show 128x128 autocorrelation kernel")
plt.imshow(abs(shiftedAC), cmap="gray")  # show 128x128 kernel 
plt.show()

print("Show 32x32 autocorrelation kernel")
n = 128 # downsize kernel to 32x32
extractedAC = abs(shiftedAC)[int(n*(3/8)):int(n*(3/8))+int(n/4), int(n*(3/8)):int(n*(3/8))+int(n/4)]
extractedAC = extractedAC
plt.imshow(abs(extractedAC), cmap="gray")  # show 32x32 kernel
plt.show()

print("Generate gaussian noise 128x128 with SD of 90")
gaussNoise = np.random.normal(0, 90,(128,128)) # genereate Gaussian noise 128x128
plt.imshow(gaussNoise, cmap="gray")  # set the color map to bone
plt.show()

print("Convolve the Gaussian noise with the 32x32 autocorrelation kernel to obtain noise pattern spatially correlated with the noise in the phantom scan")
# convolve the Gaussian noise with the 32x32 autocorrelation kernel
spatialNoise = signal.convolve2d(gaussNoise, abs(extractedAC))

plt.imshow(spatialNoise, cmap="gray")  # set the color map to bone
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could it be due to the pixel scale?  ie are you using pixels, but the scale in the paper is in mm, or vica versa?

Comment: Hi RIchard,
Thank you for responding to my message.
The orginal DICOM file containing the noise data is 128x128 and the gaussian noise which is convolved with the generated autocorrelation function is also 128x128 so the image texture should be expected to be similar. Hence, I can't see how different pixel scale should explain the texture discrepancy between the orginal noise data and the generated. Do you agree?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I had a quick look at the paper, but it wasn't too obvious at first glance what/how they were doing things. I do know that most CT's are 256x256, not 128.  I do know the noise in CT's is not gaussian and needs to be modelled by a power function (or convolution) type model that takes the scale into account.  So if you were just working in pixel units, and not correctly scaling everything to physical units, then I think you'd have problems.

Comment: Hi Richard,
Once again thank you so much for offering your advice.
I should correct myself and say that I extracted a ROI of 128x128 pixels from a uniform part of the phantom DICOM file which was 512x512 px.
The ACF was generated form the above noise. Subsequently the ACF was convolved with 128x128 image with gaussian noise where I expect the output image to have a (1D) power spectrum similar to the one in the above extracted 128x128 noise.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for my project! For the last convolution, please just convolve the measured ACF instead of the absolute value of ACF. Sign of ACF also has information.

Comment: Hi Taka, 
Thank you so much for reaching out and sorry for the latency in replying to your answer.
I'm not sure exactly what you mean by measured ACF? The abs command get the magnitude from the complex numbers from the extractAC 2D array. Does the magnitude of a complex number carry a sign?
Kind regards